# Python multiple dimension array matmul

Tags: python, arrays, matrix-multiplication

I have two 3 dimension NumPy array (10,360,90). I wanna make a matrix multiplication between two arrays.

I want to know how to consider the last two dimensions (360, 90) as a single element to make the matrix multiplication. That is, as shown in this figure, make an np.maltiply between(360, 90) arrays, and generate the final matrix as (10, 10, 360, 90).

[two 3 dimension arrays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVYC0.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be solved with [numpy.einsum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html#numpy.einsum) as follows:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(10,360,90) # first array you want to multiply
b = np.random.rand(10,360,90) # second array you want to multiply

c = np.einsum('ikl, jkl-> ijkl', a, b) # output array
```

`c` will be your final matrix with shape (10, 10, 360, 90), defined as you said.

Comment: That's great. Thanks for this answer.